# Windows 7 DNS Issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, windows-7, windows-dns

The windows XP, and Mac's can pull DHCP and use DNS from the Windows 2003 server but Windows 7 can pull an IP from DHCP but cannot resolve DNS. However, I can ping the DNS server by FQDN & IP but cant browse or connect via RDP. It won't resolve any of the other servers/workstation by name but can connect to them via IP. (Browse and RDP.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you connect to RDP using FQDN?  If so, sounds like your Win7 machine hasn't picked up a DNS suffic from your DHCP server.  Is your dhcp server handing them out?  Check using ipconfig, you should see it listed under there.

Comment: Can't connect to RDP via IP/FQDN to the DNS/DC/DHCP server. However, I can connect to everything else via IP. It's pulling a DHCP address, the gateway is correct and the DNS server.

Comment: If you manually enter the Windows Server 2003 in your Primary DNS, what happens then?

Answer (score 1):

Check for Primary DNS suffix. If PC-s are in Active Directory domain, use GPO to add prefered DNS suffix. If not, try add manualy on NIC properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like someone reset one of the switches to factory settings. The factory setting IP of the switch was the same one of the DNS/DHCP/DC server.